# AJAX request returns HTML file instead of data. ( Django & Python )

Tags: python, html, django, ajax, request

I have a profile page with user posts. People can like/dislike the posts. It works well but it reloads the page, that is why I am implementing AJAX.

The route goes like this.

Inside the profile view is the "like POST" request ending with a

> data = {
> 'likes':post.likes.all().count()
> }

> return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)"

When clicking on the like button, I can see the data on a blank page if I want to. So I know it is receiving it.

Unfortunately, when using AJAX, instead of returning the data. it returns the profile view's

> return render(request, "profile.html", context)

Here is my AJAX code

```
    const post_id = $(this).attr('id')

    const likeText = $( `.like_button${post_id} `).attr('name')
    const trim = $.trim(likeText)

    const url = $(this).attr('action')

    let res;
    const likes = $(`.like_count${post_id}`).text() || 0
    const trimCount = parseInt(likes)

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            'post_id':post_id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success', data)
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log('error', data)
        }

    })
```

Any help would be much appreciated. First time using AJAX, so as much details would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the view too.

Answer (score 1):

Not really surprising it's returning HTML since that's exactly what you're returning in the view: rendered HTML. If you want JSON you need then you want a `JSONResponse` object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

So, instead of:

```
return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

which will take the `profile.html`, inject the values from `context` and send you that as html, you should do something like:

```
response = JsonResponse({"mydata": "goes here", "some_more": data})
```

You can then parse this as JSON in your AJAX code. If it's the case that the `context` dictionary contains all the data you need and that is what you want, you can just swap out that one line:

```
response = JsonResponse(context)
```

Edit: To address the question in the comment. Suppressing the default form response in the frontend is not a Django thing, it's done with JS on the event using something like:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

See here for info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I understand that it's returning the html view but If I replace that profile render view with a JsonResponse. How can I make it stay on the same page and not send me to a blank page with the data info. 

The data I need to retrieve is in "data", The "context" dic holds other info on the profile page. 

My views looks a bit like this
def profile(request): 
---- if like { data = {} } -> return Json
return profile ( if no action is taken )

Comment: It's done in JS on the frontent. See the extra info I just added to the answer.

Comment: I already had the preventDefault, unfortunately, if I remove it, it works and sends me to the blank page with data but when I use the prevent default, I get a 404 (not found), since it stops the page from reaching the URL that applies the POST logic.

Comment: Can't you accomplish this with HttpResponse as well?

Comment: It's being used in an ajax call ,which is expecting Json.